# How to send javascript method some values from html and use them

Tags: javascript, html, methods

I'm trying to send some values to javascript. I know this is very simple. like this

```
<button id="btn" onclick="doSomething()">Click</button>
```

I can set a particular action with my desired vlaue in "doSomething()" method.

But if

```
<button id="btn" onclick="doSomething()">Click</button>
<button id="btn" onclick="doSomething()">Click</button>
```

What if two elements have two same ids and same onClick method.

Can i send some Values like this

```
<button id="btn" onclick="doSomething("someValue")">Click</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var value;
function doSomething(value) // value = someValue ?
{document.getElementById("logger").innerHTML = value;}
```

Is it possible to write something like this?
I know this is Possible by other methods But, for Practice and Training Purposes.
I would like to learn something like this.

Comment: 2 element cannot have same id

Comment: Have you tried it ? Did it fail ?

Comment: you should use single quotation marks for your parameter in your`doSomething`-call. like this: `onclick="doSomething('someValue')"`

Comment: `var value;` is actually out of the scope of `doSomething` and is useless as `value` is already defined as function parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not have two elements on the page having same IDs. It will not give you an error but it is semantically incorrect.

Now, coming to your question. You can call 1 method from N number of elements on the page and pass different values to it. Doesn't matter whether the ID is same or different.

So

```
<button id="btn" onclick="doSomething('Some value')">Click</button>
<button id="btn" onclick="doSomething('Some other value or even some value')">Click</button>
```

is perfectly fine.
However I would do something like this

```
<button class="btn" onclick="doSomething()">Click</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="doSomething()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Inline HTML event handlers should be avoided for the reasons I specify in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

> If you are just learning and practicing JavaScript, you should learn
>   to use it in a way that follows best-practices and standards.

In HTML, **`id` attribute values should always be unique**. This is how to can tell one particular element from the next, so don't duplicate `id`'s.

Second, **using inline HTML event handlers (`onclick=doSomething()`) should be avoided**. They are a very old approach to "wiring" up HTML elements to callback functions, but are not part of the "[Document Object Model (DOM) Event Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Registration-interfaces)". They cause anonymous global wrapper functions to be created behind the scenes and those functions interfere with the binding of `this` in any callback you may have. Lastly, they create "spaghetti code" (your JavaScript and HTML are intertwined), which makes reading and debugging your code more difficult. Additionally, using inline event handlers generally results in duplication of code, which violates the "[Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)" (DRY) best practice.

Instead, you should do your event wiring like this:

```js
     // Wait until the window object reports that all the DOM elements have been read into memory
     window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
       
         // Scan through the document, find the elements that are needed and store
         // references to them in variables.
         var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
         var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

         // "Wire up" the objects to the event(s) in question and supply
         // a reference to the event handling function. Since you asked 
         // about passing arguments to the callback function, we don't 
         // directly call it, we create a function around it that calls
         // it with whatever arguments you want.
       
         btn1.addEventListener("click", function(){
             doSomething("Some Value");
         });
  
         btn2.addEventListener("click", function(){
             doSomething("Some Other Value");
         });  
  
     });

     // Event callback for both buttons
     function doSomething(value){
        alert(value);
     }
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click Me</button>
<button id="btn2">Click Me</button>
```

> Do you see how the code above keeps the HTML and the JavaScript
>   completely separate? Not only is the "spaghetti code" gone and the
>   code is more readable, but this technique also follows the concept of
>   "[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)".

Answer (score 0):

You should change your IDs and make them separate names. If you want to make them do the same things just select them together. You can have to ids on 2 different buttons, Ids are unique to that specific element. You can also just give them the same class name

```
    $('#bt1, #btn2').html(value) //id
```

or

```
    $('.btn').html(value) //class
```